# How to Hide/show sharepoint list fields according to selection of mutichoice field ? with out infopath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a multiple selection field in a SharePoint list called "Electronic Document", when users select "Microsoft" from the choice, they want to see another fields, I have used jquery but didn't work, please help

here is the code

```
$("input[name='Electronic_x0020_Documents_4036b3bd-2b91-499d-93b1-dd7066f7223e_$MultiChoice']").on("click", function() {

        if($(this).val() == 'Microsoft Documents')
        {
            $('nobr:contains("Other Documents")').closest('tr').show();
                    }else{
            $('nobr:contains("Other Documents")').closest('tr').hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> //Or Get refer it from "<aclass="vglnk"     href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" rel="nofollow"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>ajax</span><span>.</span><span>googleapis</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>ajax</span><span>/</span><span>libs</span><span>/</span><span>jquery</span><span>/</span><span>1</span><span>.</span><span>3</span><span>/</span><span>jquery</span><span>.</span><span>min</span><span>.</span><span>js</span></a>"

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function()

 {
     //alert('jQuery Works');



  //Hide Reason fields initially 

  $("textarea[title$='Electronic Document']").parent('span').parent ('td').parent('tr').hide();



 //Associate a function with Drop down change event

  $("select[title$='Electronic Document:']").change(function()

  {

    if($(this).val()=='Microsoft')

     {

       $("textarea[title$='Electronic Document']").parent('span').parent    ('td').parent('tr').show();

     }

    else

     {

   $("textarea[title$='Electronic Document']").parent('span').parent ('td').parent('tr').hide();

     }

 });

 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one,  and replace the field names with your fields

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Show/hide columns based on Choice Field Selection
$("select[title='City']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='City']").val() != "other")
{
$('nobr:contains("OtherCity")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("OtherCity")').closest('tr').show();
}
});
});
```

Check the detail steps at

- [Show / hide fields based on choice field selection using jquery in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)
- [Show / hide fields based on a dropdown selection using sputility.js](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)